# Next JS with magic login, trying to grab the router after being redirected from email login

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js

I am using magic login in javascript and next js to add users to my app, it works just fine, but the problem I am having is. When a user lands back on the page I have to manually refresh the page to get my data. I have tried checking for the url param, and reloading if it exists then changing the changing the url to not have the url param so it doesn't loop.

But the router isn't even found after clicking the login button from the email sent from magic login.

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export const GET_DAD_HAT = gql`
  query FindUserByID($id: ID!) {
    findUserByID(id: $id) {
      _id
      hats {
        data {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

function useAuth() {
  const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR("/api/user", fetcher);

  const loading = user?.token === false || user === undefined;

  return {
    user,
    loading,
    error,
  };
}

export default function Profile() {
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("window", window);
    console.log(Object.keys(router.query)[0]);
    if (Object.keys(router.query)[0] === "magic_credentials") {
      router.reload(window.location.pathname);
      window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/" + "profile");
    }
    if (loading) {
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <main>{loading ? "Loading..." : <Data user={user} />}</main>
    </Layout>
  );
}

const Data = ({ user }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DAD_HAT, {
    variables: { id: user.id },
  });

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  if (error) return <h1>{error.message}</h1>;

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
};
```

What happens is the data is just stuck on Loading until I manually hit refresh, after being redirected to the app from the email login flow.

UPDATE: I made a reproducible sandbox. https://omg5u.sse.codesandbox.io/login-magic

Enter your email, click the login link sent to email.

Feel free to use disposable email service like https://getnada.com/
if it's not blocked

When you arrive on profile page see that it is just loading, until you hit refresh then it should show your user id, and an empty array for data.

UPDATE: It looks like when I first land on the page the cookie lookup for fauna_client in the fetch to the user api route returns undefined. However after refreshing it returns the cookie. If I inspect the cookie is there before hitting refresh, but if I look in the terminal for next, the cookie is created after it is looked for. I think it has something to do with Magic redirect in the login api route creating the cookie after magic is logged in.

Still quite confused.

Comment: Why not `router.push('/profile')`?

Comment: You could also use [Redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

Comment: oh redirects might just work. I can have auth-verify page and redirect to their profile. Let me try thanks

Comment: hmm I still don't understand even after going from a auth-verify page to the profile page it still requires a refresh for my data to load. Hmm

Comment: Can you create a min reproducible [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: Not really, Im hooked up to my db instance and everything depends on it working, so don't see how I would create a sandbox. I could make the repo public tho if that helps

Comment: Hopefully this helps https://github.com/wispyco/dadhats/tree/magic

Comment: Sure that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234979/discussion-between-psygik-and-anders-kitson).

Comment: I actually have to do my day job now, but I will come back to it. This evening. Thanks for any advice thus far.

Comment: @PsyGik I added the CodeSandbox, above in my original question with instructions and what is going wrong. Hope you can help. thanks. Here is the file I am redirecting to https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-feather-omg5u?file=/pages/profile.js

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the following on a auth-verify page and a login-verify api route

```
useEffect(() => {
    finishEmailRedirectLogin();
  }, [router.query]);

  const finishEmailRedirectLogin = () => {
    if (router.query.magic_credential)
      magicClient.auth
        .loginWithCredential()
        .then((didToken) => authenticateWithServer(didToken));
  };

  // Send token to server to validate
  const authenticateWithServer = async (didToken) => {
    let res = await fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + didToken,
      },
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      // Set the UserContext to the now logged in user
      let userMetadata = await magicClient.user.getMetadata();
      // await setUser(userMetadata);
      router.push("/profile");
    }
  };
```

```
import { Magic } from "@magic-sdk/admin";

// Initiating Magic instance for server-side methods
const magic = new Magic(process.env.MAGIC_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function login(req, res) {
  try {
    const didToken = req.headers.authorization.substr(7);
    await magic.token.validate(didToken);
    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```